# How to display the column names on group by result in Python when writing into CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input data like this,

```
ID days
1  02
1  24
2  12
3  10
```

Expected result in csv file should be

```
ID Avg. days
1  13
2  12
3  10
```

with my code, I am able to get only the mean value , not able to get ID. But I need it both.

```
ID = tempx.groupby('ID')['days'].mean()
ID.to_csv("file1.csv", sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index = False)
```

will anyone please help me how to get the columns as header with group by result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.groupby('ID')` sets `'ID'` to be the index. Either save your file like this:

```
ID = tempx.groupby('ID')['days'].mean()
ID.to_csv("file1.csv", sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index = True)
```

Or groupby with `as_index = False`

```
ID = tempx.groupby('ID', as_index = False)['days'].mean()
ID.to_csv("file1.csv", sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index = False)
```

Comment: Dear Ken, thanks for support.
it's working after removing index=False. Now I am able to see the header in my csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass `index=False`

```
tempx.groupby('ID').days.mean().to_frame('Avg. days').to_csv(
    'file.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Maybe `encoding='utf-8'` is necessary

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name`:

```
ID = tempx.groupby('ID')['days'].mean().reset_index(name='Avg. days')
print (ID)
   ID  Avg. days
0   1         13
1   2         12
2   3         10

ID.to_csv("file1.csv", sep=',',encoding='utf-8',index = False)
```